# Adding attributes to instance elements in XForms

Tags: xforms

I have an instance that looks like the following:

```
<root>
    <switch ID="1">
        <foo/>
        <bar/>
    </switch>
    <switch ID="2">
        <foo/>
        <bar/>
    </switch>
</root>
```

I'm trying to create a trigger that adds an `enabled` attribute to a switch element. I've been using something like the following to add new child nodes to the switches, but as far as I can tell, this same method won't work to add only the attribute. This trigger is in a `xf:repeat` block, and goes away once the "bar" element has been added for the specific switch:

```
<xf:trigger ref=".[not(bar)]">
    <xf:label>Add "bar" Element</xf:label>
    <xf:insert ev:event="DOMActivate" context="../switch[index('switch-repeat')]" 
        nodeset="foo" at="foo" position="after" 
        origin="instance('presets')/bar"/>
</xf:trigger>
```

I've been thinking about copying the contents of the switch element into another instance with the enabled attribute, something like `<switch enabled="true/>`, and then replacing the original with that, but that seems a little bit roundabout for the task, and I might have to do the same thing to preserve the ID attributes anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guided by Alain's comment, I found [this mention](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms/#data-mutation-patterns-copy-attributelist) in the XForms standard for copying attribute lists into elements. This works exactly how I would've hoped.

The code I'm using to add the attributes is the following:

```
<xf:trigger ref=".[not(@enabled)]">
    <xf:label>Add "enabled" attribute</xf:label>
    <xf:insert ev:event="DOMActivate" context="../switch[index('switch-repeat')]"
        origin="instance('presets')/switch/@enabled"/>
</xf:trigger>
```

where `instance('presets')/switch` is `<switch enabled="true"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

XForms 1.1 does not allow to create an element or an attribute but just to copy it from somewhere else.

XForms 2.0 does. Implementations may have already their own extension for that.

Comment: Does that mean there's a way to copy just the attribute from another element? That would work for my problem.